# Why can't I launch the Java SSH Client from the AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

In the AWS Management Console, I select an EC2 instance and then I click "Connect" from the Instance Actions menu. I see the following popup window:

[image]

Instead of the fields I should normally see, I get the above message about enabling java in my browser. But java **is enabled** in my browser. I tested it with [this page](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)  to confirm. I'm running Java SE 6 Update 24.

I'm using Google Chrome v20.0 on Linux Mint 13 64bit. I also tried with Firefox and the result is the same. I can access Java SSH Client without any problem from my Windows box, so it may be a Linux-specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox or safari, it works fine.

Refer to the link below for more information.

Chrome browser versions 42 and above. Starting with Chrome version 42 (released April 2015), Chrome has disabled the standard way in which browsers support plugins.
https://java.com/en/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try option 1, a stand alone ssh and then open terminal use the chmod command to change the permissions then ssh -i.... command(Example is given in the Launch instance box on AWS).

After doing this you will see bitmap on your terminal, that means you are in.

Then use cd apps/parse/htdocs.  This will take you to htdocs where most parse server files are stored.  Then use vi filename.js which opens a tex editor to edit the file you want.

Hope that was useful.

Answer (score -3):

Try with java 32 bit version.. most browsers don't support 64 bit java..